# Как сделать первую букву в строке жирной? - Android

Tags: java, android

Пытался через `Html.fromHtml`, но не получается. Наверное потому что в проекте используются сторонний шрифт. Искал ответ на этом сайте, но тут есть предложение только как сделать заглавную букву.

Comment: Можно кроме SpannableString использовать шрифты, для папки assets/fonts, чтоб сделать первую букву еще круче, тип как в книгах там первая буква на пол страницы. А если динамически, то скорее всего в TextView будет передаваться две конкатенированные) строки , одна содержит большую букву, вторая - текст(если заполнена первая).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
if(text.length()>0)
   ssb.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(ssb);
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В файле ресурса обернуть нужную букву тегом `<b></b>`

***res/values/strings.xml***

```
<resources>
 <string name="my_text"><b>H</b>ello World!</string>
</resources>
```

***res/layaout/activity_main.xml***

```
<TextView
 android:text="@string/my_text"
 android:textSize="22sp"
 android:padding="5dp"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А есть вариант как это сделать с помощью кода? Просто может случится так, что строка будет динамическая и этот вариант не подойдет.